Как получить значение setInterval?
В примерах в интернете результат работы setinterval выводят в консоль:
let a = 10;

    setInterval(function() {
    a = a + 1;
  console.log(a);
},1000);

Но мне нужно эти значения дальне использовать для других вычислений внутри программы.


let a = 10;

setInterval(function() {
  a = a + 1;
}, 1000);

console.log(a);



Так не работает. Если в функции добавить (return а;) тоже не работает.
Как получать значения а чтобы дальше его использовать в других вычислениях?

У вас все работает, просто сначала отработает console.log(), а уже позже отработает интервал. Какого поведения вы хотите достить?

Выполните другие вычисления после оператора a = a + 1;.

Console.log работает только если он внутри функции. А мне нужно вывести значение (а) наружу. Обычно же для этого пишут (return a) в конце функции, но так не работает. То есть я дальше хочу сравнивать эту (а) с помощью if else, например. Мне ее значение нужно в глобальной области видимости наверное, или передать в другую функцию.

setInterval выполнится через секунду после того, как отработает консоль.лог. Поставьте в код setTimeout(() => console.log(a), 1300) и увидите измененное значение. Если хотите работать с переменной сразу после изменения, то ниже есть пример или используйте промисы, к примеру. Реализация зависит от конкретной цели

Я наверное не очень понимаю что значит консоль. Какой толк что там видно значение. Мне же нужно это значение получить и как то дальше использовать. Например если написано а =10+1;.  То потом у меня в программе а станет 11. А если внутри setinterval это же вычисление сделается, то как я получу 11? Я только в консоле на него могу посмотреть, а внутри программы а не меняется

Ну вместо console.log() выполняйте нужные действия, в чем проблема? console это для демонстрации того, что лежит в переменной. вот тут пример, как выполнить действие после итерации в интервале - т.е. меняете значение и вызываете функцию, в которой прописан нужный код. на самом деле не очень еще понятно, зачем вам вообще этот интервал и как он используется. Возможно, если добавите в вопрос весь ваш код и объясните, какую цель преследуете, то получите более точный ответ

Хочу как то организовать логически части программы. Одна часть делает что то одно с переменной, потом в зависимости от того, что получилось, начинает работать другая часть. То есть чтобы разные части кода имели доступ к хранилищу переменных и одна часть могла бы использовать результат работы другой части. Наверное нужно использовать объект, и чтобы разные функции могли бы по очереди брать и изменять в нем данные

setInterval - вызывается много раз, соответственно переменная будет меняться много раз - ты хочешь каждый раз выполнять какой-то код, при изменении переменной?

Просто хотел чтобы эта изменённая переменная была в глобальной области видимости и другие функции могли бы использовать ее новое значение. Но кажется так и будет, я просто не разобрался как работает консоль.

@user668824, другие функции и так могут использовать ее новое значение - нужно чтобы они вызывались после того, как это значение присвоится и этого можно добиться разными способами

У вас уже все правильно. Просто попробуйте в консоли запустить свой код
let a = 10;

    setInterval(function() {
    a = a + 1;
},1000);

А потом периодически начните вызывать console.log(a);
И Вы заметите, что оно изменяется.

А в данном примере:
let a = 10;

    setInterval(function() {
    a = a + 1;
},1000);

console.log(a);

вы настолько быстро смотрите на результат, что он даже не успевает измениться

Интересно, кто поставил минус? При том, что сам автор вопроса счёл ответ полезным



function useAForCalculations(x) {
    console.log(x);
}
let a = 10;
setInterval(function() {
    a += 1;
    useAForCalculations(a);
}, 1000)




Ну вы хоть переменные в фукнции поменяйте, что бы было понятно, что там выводится. Перекрытие переменных - очень плохая практика
